# Child div has more width than parent even with border-box

Tags: html, css

Hello i have a parent `div` and inside a child `div`.

Parent `div` has `1300px` width at fullsize screen.
But if i use `width:100%` on child div , it takes `1600px width`.

I used `box-sizing:border-box;` property but the problem persists.
What should i do the fix that problem ?

I made a quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh3bgc5u/)

[Image of the Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkfi2.png)

Comment: The fiddle has been supplied

Comment: When using `position absolute`, the element's parent also need positioning, where `relative` is the more used, as Trix suggest.

Comment: If you have to use `position absolute`, an alternative is to set left/right - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57251590/4271117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this:

```
.inner-content{ position: relative }
```

Comment: this worked like a charm , but could you explain please how `position:relative;` solves this, cause im really confused?

Comment: Yes, the absolute positioned child, finds the very first above relative positioned parent as base.

Comment: Its `inner-content` not `inner-conten`

Answer (score 1):

Give

```
.inner-content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #333;
}
#asideHead {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow
}
.inner-content {
  background: red;
  height: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-content">
  <div style="" id="asideHead">
    <div id="mod_improved_ajax_login-99">

      <a class="logBtn selectBtn" onclick="return false" href="/index.php?option=com_users&amp;view=login">
        <span class="loginBtn">Log in</span>
      </a>


      <a class="regBtn selectBtn  " href="/index.php?option=com_users&amp;view=registration">
        <span class="loginBtn">Register</span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```