# width: 100% of an absolute positioned element is bigger than the parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div with unknown width and height, this div is one of the children of a bigger div.

```css
#myDiv {
    /* Blah blah blah */
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that the `#inner` div doesn't fit properly, it's way bigger than its parent `#myDiv` while its width and height are set to `100%`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: position relative to myDiv will fix the issue

Comment: will not, because I have many elements in "#myDiv" and in that case the arrange of children elements will be going wrong

Comment: so what you are having is not an issue and logic :) your element is absolute and since the parent is not positioned, so it's not relative to it's parent but another ancestor so with:100% is not from his parent

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By making any element `position: absolute;` means: place me to the first parent that is `position: relative;` which is not always equal to its parent element.

And if there are other children you need to remember that one of them will be places "under" the element posiotionated absolutely.

Comment: `place me to the first parent that is position: relative;`--> not exact, to the first **ancestor** positioned (relative, absolute or fixed)

Answer (score 25):

Accepted answer didn't solve it for me. Parent element was already `position: relative;`.

This is what worked for me:

In the child element, instead of using `height:100%` use `top:0; bottom:0;` to fill up height, and `left:0; right:0;` to fill width up.

```css
.parent{
   position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer should be objectively correct, it just fails to mention that you should need top, bottom, left, and right attributes (I think). I upvoted both, because they are seemingly incomplete from each other.

Comment: Agreed. This was the only answer that solved my issue

Answer (score 9):

One reason an absolutely-positioned child element can stick out from its relatively-positioned parent is if the **parent has padding**.

Take the following example:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff000099;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the actual width and height of the child is the same as the parent, however since the parent has padding-top and padding-left, the child's content is placed after the parent's padding. This makes the child stick out at the bottom and the right.

There are different ways to handle this, depending on the desired outcome.

**If you want the child to perfectly cover the parent**, either use [bets's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57251590/811240) and set the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` attributes on the child instead of the `width` and `height`, **or** just keep the `width` and `height` at 100% and set `top` and `left` to 0, like this:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ff000044;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  I am parent content
  <div class="child">I am child content</div>
</div>
```

**If you want the child to occupy all the space within the padding on the parent**, you can use `calc()` to remove the parent's padding from the child div:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: #ff000099;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

(Just remember to remove both the left and right padding from the child's width and the top and bottom from its height. That's why I am multiplying the padding by 2.)

**Combining these**, if you want the child to start after the top and left padding, but not stick out the right or bottom, only subtract the top and left paddings from the height and width of the child:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: #ff000099;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```